# Difference of linear transformation of convex function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I'm trying to show that for constants $a,b > 0$, and a convex, continuously differentiable function $f$ with $f(0) = 0$ that $x_1 > x_2 > 0$ implies $f(-a-b x_1) - f(-b x_1) \geq f(-a-b x_2) - f(-b x_2)$.

It may or may not be true because its an auxiliary result I'm trying to show for other work. If it helps, I can also add more structure to the problem. In particular $f$ is a cumulant generating function (CGF) of a distribution. As an example, if $f$ is the CGF of a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the result is that the above inequality is equivalent to:

$a b \sigma^2 x_1 > a b \sigma^2 x_2$

So the proposition holds.

Here are a few lines of Mathematica code that takes a distribution and checks the inequality.

```
cum[t_]:=CumulantGeneratingFunction[mydist,t]
mydist=NormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]]; 
val=cum[-a-b x1]-cum[-b x1]>cum[-a-b x2]-cum[-b x2];
Simplify[val]
Simplify[val, a > 0 && b > 0 && x1 > x2 > 0]
```

Which gives $a b \sigma^2 (x1-x2)>0$ and $\sigma^2 > 0$, so its obviously true. It always seems to hold for distributions I've checked. Also, when I draw a graph of the proposition it seems highly plausible.

If it's not true, a counter example would be helpful so I can pin down a set of parameters or distributions where it is true. Thanks!